# Holomorphic function on a square that vanishes on a side

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to solve the following:

> Let $S \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ be a "full" square, and let $f:S\to\mathbb{C}$ be a function holomorphic on $S°$ and continuous on $\bar{S}$. Prove that if $f$ is identically zero on one of the sides of $S$, then $f$ is constant.

I'm not to sure on how to proceed, so far I've tried to use the maximum modulus principle restricting $f$ to certain regions inside the square. I'm trying to exploit the idea of assuming $f$ non-constant, and then using that this implies the maximum of $f$ is achieved on the border of the region, for any connected open subset of the square (that may conveniently contain the side where $f$ vanishes on its border).

Thoughts?

Comment: Without loss of generality, $S$ is the square with vertices $\pm 1,\, \pm i$. Consider $g(z) = f(z)\cdot f(iz)\cdot f(-z) \cdot f(-iz)$.

Comment: Ok, so $g$ vanishes on the border of $S$ and by the m.m.p. it must be zero on the whole square. Then, let's take $x_n \in B_{\frac{1}{n}}(0) \ \ \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$. For each of these, one of the factors of $g$ must be zero, so we get a sequence of points where $f$ vanishes that tends to zero. We can then apply the indentity theorem. 

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes. By the way, if you know the reflection principle, that gives the result under weaker assumptions.

Comment: Cool, thanks a lot!